# Are all elements of a bounded sequence also elements of some convergent subsequence (proof suggestion)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following proposition (no idea if it's actually true or not):

> All elements of a bounded sequence are also elements of some convergent subsequence.

The idea I thought about, laid out informally, is:

> Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence, so by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem
> it has a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}$.
>
> Since $a_{n_k}$ is also bounded, by using Bolzano-Weierstrass again,
> we can get a subsequence $a_{n_{k_i}}$, which is also convergent (and
> to the same limit as $a_{n_k}$, of course) . In that manner we can
> generate an infinite amount of convergent subsequences of $a_n$, and
> the set of these subsequences is countable.
>
> We can take any element of the set $\left\{a_n\:|\:n\in N,\:a_n\notin a_{n_k}\right\}$, which is also countable, and "insert" each
> individual one of them before the first element of a different
> convergent subsequence (there are infinitely many), and so it turns
> out that all elements of $a_n$ are also elements of *some* convergent
> subsequences, as requested.

As I said, I don't even know if this proposition is correct, it just bothered me so I tried to ascertain its validity. I don't know if this proof is reliable, becausen infinity is a tricky beast... reviews and corrections would be very helpful :).

Comment: Inserting finitely many terms into a sequence can’t change the convergence properties of the sequence. So if you have a single convergent subsequence, you can then “splice in” any finite number of terms from the original sequence that might have been excluded, and the result will still be a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I don’t see why it’s needed in your argument to get infinitely many convergent subsequences, so I’m worried I’m missing something about what you’re aiming to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is nearly correct (two minor mistakes) but overcomplicated.

- "and the set of these subsequences is countable": no, it has the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).
- '"insert" each individual one of them before the first element of a different convergent subsequence' is the good idea but

  - not before the *first* element, because its index in the sequence $(a_n)$ might be smaller than the index of the element you want to insert;
  - you do not need to do this with distinct subsequences of your convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k}).$ You can do this directly with that subsequence. Alternatively:

For any $n\in\Bbb N,$ let $k_0\in\Bbb N$ be such that $n_{k_0}>n.$ Then, the subsequence
whose first term is $a_n$ and the following terms are $(a_{n_k})_{k\ge k_0}$ is convergent.

Comment: Oh thank you! So just to make that clear, you're saying that the proposition, and the proof, are both correct (albeit with the proof having a superfluous part)?